# Is this a reasonable way to get >50 capacitive touch sensors?

Tags: capacitance, touch-panel

I'm looking to include 50-100 capacitive-touch sensors in a project. I've found these [SPI 12-key capacitive touch sensors](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1982). Would it be reasonable to use several of these for such a project, or is there a more natural solution?

I'm building a chessboard-like "grid" with 7x7-10x10 touchable squares, ca 3x3cm.

Comment: Can some cheap touchscreen for kiosks help?

Comment: What sort of physical touch sensors do you have in mind? Glass screen? Metal contacts? Something else?

Comment: @duskwuff My primary plan is copper contacts under a PMMA sheet, so that I can light the surface up.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I wouldn't recommend any solution involving the MPR121. That part was discontinued by NXP in 2015 -- Adafruit is probably building boards with old stock.

Comment: Thank you @duskwuff , I didn't know. Is the disadvantage to using discontinued parts that it would be hard to order new ones? Anything else I'm not realising?

Comment: @Anna That's precisely it. When the parts run out and you need a replacement, you're hosed.

Comment: Depends on whether you want a see through sensor like an LCD touch screen. There are plenty of both resistive and capacitive overlays and controllers. Just search on Digikey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that many active zones, you're going to want to think about matrix methods rather than completely individual electrodes. Here's a relevant application note from Freescale:

[Designing Touch Sensing Electrodes](https://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3863.pdf)